# Data Binding Many-ended Associations

Tags: data-binding, grails, spring-mvc, groovy, propertyeditor

Assume I want to databind HTTP parameters to an instance of

```
class Continent {
  Integer id
  String name
  Country country
}
```

where the `Country` class looks something like:

```
class Country {
  Integer id
  String name
  Currency currency
  // other properties
}
```

If I want to bind `Continent.country` to an instance of `Country` that already exists and can be retrieved using:

```
interface CountryService {
  Country get(Integer countryId)
}
```

A simple way to do this is to define a `PropertyEditor` that can convert the country's ID to the correspdonding `Country` instance, e.g.

```
public class ProductTypeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    CountryService countryService // set this via dependency injection

    void setAsText(String paramValue) {
        if (paramValue) 
            value = countryService.get(paramValue.toInteger())
    }

    public String getAsText() {
        value?.id.toString()
    }
}
```

If instead I want to databind an instance of

```
class Continent {
  Integer id
  String name
  Collection<Country> countries
}
```

and the IDs of the countries are sent in a HTTP (array parameter). Is there any easy way to bind the `Collection<Country>`, e.g. by defining another `PropertyEditor`?

Comment: Why would you bind to Collection<Country> and not Continent? I imagine you would want to bind to the continent id instead of the list of countries? Right?

Comment: You can assume for the sake of this example that the user can create new continents, but the continents may only contain countries that have already been created.

Comment: can't you just comma separate the country codes and load each one? If each one is cached or you use a nice single line SQL statement then you should be able to load all in one request? Or where you looking for something easier?

Comment: Ideally I'm looking to write a `PropertyEditor` that can do the job for me, in the same way that it can bind a single-ended association

Answer (score 0):

PropertyEditors are only wrappers around String <-> object. You will have to do marshaling and unmarshaling of data your self. Just like you have done above for Country.

I would create a service that does

`Collection<Country> getCountries(int[] id)`

then use the PropertyEditor to split and use your service. I don't think you will find a better solution. You can do something like

```
  void setAsText(String paramValue) {
        ids = param.split(",")
        // make each id an int
        value = service.getCountries(ids)
    }
```